# Unable to Create a CloudWatch Healthcheck via Ansible

Tags: boto, ansible

I have a inventory file which has a RDS endpoint as :

```
[ems_db]
syd01-devops.ce4l9ofvbl4z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

I wrote the following play book to create a Cloudwatch ALARM :

```
---

    - name: Get instance ec2 facts
      debug: var=groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]
      register: ems_db_name

    - name: Display
      debug: var=ems_db_name

    - name: Create CPU utilization metric alarm
      ec2_metric_alarm:
          state: present
          region: "{{aws_region}}"
          name: "{{ems_db_name}}-cpu-util"
          metric: "CPUUtilization"
          namespace: "AWS/RDS"
          statistic: Average
          comparison: ">="
          unit: "Percent"
          period: 300
          description: "It will be triggered when CPU utilization is more than 80% for 5 minutes"
          dimensions: { 'DBInstanceIdentifier' : ems_db_name }
          alarm_actions: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:493552970418:cloudwatch_test
          ok_actions: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:493552970418:cloudwatch_test
```

But this results in

```
TASK: [cloudwatch | Get instance ec2 facts] *********************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]": "syd01-devops"
    }
}

TASK: [cloudwatch | Display] ************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "ems_db_name": {
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "var=groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]", 
                "module_complex_args": {}, 
                "module_name": "debug"
            }, 
            "var": {
                "groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]": "syd01-devops"
            }, 
            "verbose_always": true
        }
    }
}

TASK: [cloudwatch | Create CPU utilization metric alarm] ********************** 
failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
msg: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://monitoring.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-08-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>f30470a3-2d65-11e6-b7cb-cdbbbb30b60b</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

What is wrong here? What can i do to solve this ? I am new to this but surely this seems some syntax issue with me or the way i am picking up the inventory endpoint split.

Comment: so, uh, do you work with @nishant-singh, [who posted a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674377/creating-cloudwatch-alarm-metrics-using-ansible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable from debug isn't being assigned in the first debug statement, though you may be able to if you change it to a message and enclose it with quotes and double braces (untested):

```
 - name: Get instance ec2 facts
   debug: msg="{{groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]}}"
   register: ems_db_name
```

However, I would use the [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) module in that task (instead of debug) and assign that value to it.  That way, you can reuse it in this and subsequent calls to a play.

```
 - name: Get instance ec2 facts
   set_fact: ems_db_name="{{groups.ems_db[0].split('.')[0]}}"
```

**UPDATE:** Add a `threshold: 80.0` to the last task, and the dimensions needs to use the instance id encapsulated with double braces.

Comment: Tried this still same error , ps i am running this on `localhost` , should i be concerned?

Comment: Did you try the set_fact or the debug modifications?

Comment: Localhost won't make a difference, but the fact for set_fact will get set to localhost.

Comment: i tried with set_fact , i am not sure whats `MalformedInput` , how can i check ?

Comment: MalformedInput means what you sent was not in the correct format.  Check the examples from ec2_metric_alarm and make sure you are sending the correct arguments.

Comment: Did the second task now return the correct result ("syd01-devops")?

Comment: yes,   `{"ansible_facts": {"ems_db_name": "syd01-devops"}}

TASK: [cloudwatch | Display] ************************************************** 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "ems_db_name": "syd01-devops"
    }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114118/discussion-between-pythonfreak-and-theo).

Comment: Reading more on the module, I think you're missing a threshold.  You set to check for CPU Utilization greater than...what value?

Comment: Ohhh RIGHT , i think thats what was missing , will test and update you !!

Comment: i tried with `dimensions: { 'DBInstanceIdentifier' : '{{ ems_db_name }}' }
` and added threshold , still same

Comment: Found the error : "evaluation_periods": 1, i missed it